# Java SSL get end entity and intermediate certificate from chain

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am retrieving certificate chain by connecting to HTTPS site from java code using **SSLSocket**. Now how can I get end entity and first intermediate certificate from certificate chain?

1.Is first entry in **X509Certificate[]** is always of end entity and
   seconds  entry is of first intermediate?
2.If not is there any way to find out same in java.

Comment: 1. Yes and yes. 2. See (1).

Comment: Thanks EJP......